# Negate a regex sith re and sub

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string

```
t1 = 'hello, how are you ?'
```

I just want to get this :

```
t2 = 'hello how are you'
```

So I'm trying to use sub() from with a negate regex like this :

```
t2 = re.sub(r'^([a-z])','',t1)
```

But I don't succeed in.

What is the best way to remove punctuations ?

Thanks

Comment: I hope this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
re.sub("[^a-zA-Z ]","",'hello, how are you ?').rstrip()
```

The rstrip is there to get rid of the trailing whitespace left after getting rid of the question mark.

Of course, this is only if you really want to use regex.  Any of the ways in the question that @f43d65 linked will probably work fine and likely be faster as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to remove punctuation doesn't use regular expressions.

```
# Python 3
import string

transmapping = str.maketrans(None, None, string.punctuation)

t1 = 'hello, how are you ?'
t2 = t1.translate(transmapping).strip()
```

Here are the Python3 docs for [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

```
# Python 2
import string

t1 = 'hello, how are you ?'
t2 = t1.translate(None, deletechars=string.punctuation).strip()
```

Here are the Python2 docs for [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) (not used here) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

Using regular expressions to do string translation is a bit like using a backhoe when a prybar would do. It's huge, unwieldy, and likely to foul things up if you don't do it *juuuust* right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to remove the last punctuation and it's a question mark:

/[\?]$/

That's saying remove anything in the brackets that's at the end of a string.